# hazelcast IList is copyonwrite?

Tags: hazelcast

If I am iterating over a list at client A, and client B removes one item of the same list at the same time.  Will client A encounter `ConcurrentModifyException`?
Or, since `Ilist` is "copy on write", will client A be able access the removed item?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have changed some of the spelling and grammar and I believe I have made the question more clear to people who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast *IList* acts like a concurrent-safe list. There is no copy-on-write behaviour or modification exceptions.

Each *IList* is stored on one server in the cluster.

When client A does `hazelcast.getList("name")` it gets a proxy reference to that list on the server. When client B does `hazelcast.getList("name")` it gets another proxy reference to the same list object.

If client A does `list.remove(0)` this removes the first item from the 
server's list. If client B then does `list.get(0)` it won't get that item

Try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HazelcastInstance server = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IList<String> iList_0 = server.getList("something");
        iList_0.add("one");
        iList_0.add("two");
        iList_0.add("three");
        iList_0.add("four");
        iList_0.add("five");

        HazelcastInstance client_1 = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
        HazelcastInstance client_2 = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

        IList<String> iList_1 = client_1.getList("something");
        IList<String> iList_2 = client_2.getList("something");

        Iterator<String> iterator = iList_1.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("size()==" + iList_1.size() + ",hasNext()==" + iterator.hasNext());
            System.out.println("remove(0)==" + iList_2.remove(0));
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            System.out.println("next()==" + iterator.next());
            if (iList_1.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("get(0)==" + iList_1.get(0));
            }
        }

        client_2.shutdown();
        client_1.shutdown();
        server.shutdown();
    }
```

Client 1 iterates across the list at the time it got the iterator. Client 2 can remove items without it affecting the iterator. Client 1 when it does `get(0)` gets the actual front item.

Comment: tks.  if a list has 10 items,  client A executes it = list.iterator() , while(it.hasNext()){print(it.next())} . client B removes one item at the same time.  then client A will invoke "print" method 9 times?

Comment: Perhaps a simpler explanation is that `Iterator` returns a clone of the `IList` so `hasNext()` would give the items as the time the iterator was taken. Ordinal based activities such as `get(0)` work off the server's copy. Two threads doing `remove(0)` remove two items. So in the code snippet the `remove(0)` is risky as the list may be empty.